# Stretch Slider to fit Grid/GridViewItem/GridView [C#, XAML]

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, gridview, slider

I really need your help now. I´ve tried a few thousands solutions, but nothing worked for me. This is a part of a page built with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 for Windows. I want to make to make the Slider (named slider_1) responsive, so it should fill the rest of the page regardless the Screen Solution (cannot use fixed Heights):

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            .........
        </Grid>


        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="secGrid">
            <GridView x:Name="source">
                <GridViewItem x:Name="item_1">
                    <Grid x:Name="container_1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="name_1" Height="39" Text="123"></TextBlock>
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="toggle_on_1" Content="ON"></Button>
                        <Slider Grid.Row="2" x:Name="slider_1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="3" x:Name="toggle_off_1" Height="39"  Content="OFF"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </GridViewItem>

            </GridView>
        </Grid>
```

Thought I could get it to work by binding the Height of the Slider to the ActualHeight of the "secGrid", but this is not suitable for my purpose, even if it seemed to work well in combination with a converter:

```
    <Slider Grid.Row="2" x:Name="slider_1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=secGrid}"/>
```

Tried to set VerticalAligment/VerticalContentAligment to "Stretch", but it did not work.
Its important that it is responsive to other Screen Solutions.

Can anybody help me? Do I have to use another type of Element besides the inner Grid named container_1? This is driving me crazy....

PS: Sorry for mistakes in language. I´m german :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Auto sizing grid creates problem for slider scaling as Auto means "size to row content", and * means "size proportional to grid".

**Auto means that a row is given as much height as the elements within it require.**

**The height of * sized row is calculated by allocating space for the auto, and fixed  height rows, and then dividing up the remaining space.**

below code works fine if I set height to rowdefination 2 or if I set height to grid

```
  <Grid>
    <GridView x:Name="source">
        <GridViewItem x:Name="item_1"  >
            <Grid x:Name="container_1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="name_1" Height="39" Text="123"></TextBlock>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="toggle_on_1" Content="ON"></Button>
                <Slider Grid.Row="2" x:Name="slider_1" Orientation="Vertical"   HorizontalAlignment="center"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="3" x:Name="toggle_off_1" Height="39"  Content="OFF"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```